# Capistrano mail recipe after a deployment with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, rubygems, capistrano

I would like to send a mail "via" capistrano once I deployed. So after deployment is finished capistrano should send a mail with some information to a list of recipients.

I found this plugin/gem: http://code.google.com/p/capistrano-mailer/ but it doesn't look like its rails3 ready and the setup confuses me a lot.

Does anyone know of a gem or does have a own recipe for to realize such a thing?

thx

Answer (score 3):

Check out this gist, designed for Rails 3: https://gist.github.com/955917

Basically, you create an ActionMailer class to handle your notifications, and then set up a hook inside your `deploy.rb` file to call this mailer.